# Using JNA to call the __cpuid function on Windows

Tags: java, windows, jna, cpuid

I need to get processor information (vendor, model, etc.) in Java. I would normally use C/C++ but unfortunately this has to be done in Java for my current project. I am using JNA for native access, and I've declared my JNA `Library` as follows:

```
public interface CLibrary extends Library {
    public void __cpuid(int[] CPUInfo, int InfoType);
}
```

I'm attempting to make the call like this:

```
CLibrary c = (CLibrary) Native.loadLibrary("msvcrt", CLibrary.class);
int[] CPUInfo = new int[4];
c.__cpuid(CPUInfo, 0);
```

However I'm getting `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'intrin': The specified module could not be found.` which probably means I'm loading the wrong library.

So what is the library I need to load to get access to the `__cpuid` function on Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As __cpuid is a compiler instrinsic ([see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hskdteyh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) rather than a function, there is no associated DLL.  You'll need to write your own.

Comment: Some intrinsics may be available as functions in addition to their inline versions.  The system error seems to indicate that the "__cpuid" symbol would be found in an "intrin" library.  You might check whether such a DLL exists.

Comment: @technomage: I would expect the documentation to reflect the existence of a function version where there is one.  There's also no sign of it in the header files.